# Как обновить значение CLOB столбца из файла?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, update, clob

Есть таблица со столбцом  `CLOB`, в котором содержатся большие XML документы.

Нужно обновить значение этого столбца для одной азписи таблицы.

Пробовал обычный синтаксис запроса на обновление и вставлял большой XML документ внутри одиночных кавычек, но одиночная кавычка заменялась 2-мя одиночными кавычками и SQL Developer просто делал кнопку выполнения запроса неактивной.

```
update tableName t 
set t.clobField = 'XML документ из файла'
where t.anotherField='value';
```

Как можно в этом запросе задать XML документ из файла?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to update CLOB column in oracle sql developer from a physical file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31260154) от участника [@teenup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353512/teenup)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/31260154

Answer (score 3):

Надо создать функцию, которая считает данные из файла в переменную с типом данных `CLOB` и вернёт её как результат.

Рабочий пример:

```
create table tclob (id number, filename varchar2 (64), doc clob)
/
insert into tclob values (1, 'test.xml', empty_clob ());
commit;

create or replace function clobLoader (filename varchar2) return clob is
    bf bfile := bfilename ('TEMPFILES', filename);
    cl clob;
begin
    if dbms_lob.fileexists (bf) = 1 then
        dbms_lob.createtemporary (cl, true);
        dbms_lob.fileopen (bf, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
        dbms_lob.loadfromfile (cl, bf, dbms_lob.getlength (bf));
        dbms_lob.fileclose (bf);
    else cl := empty_clob ();
    end if;
    return cl;
end;
/
```

Пример использования:

```
update tclob t 
set t.doc = clobLoader (t.filename) 
where t.id = 1; 

1 row updated.
```